# Understand /var/run/systemd/sessions/2 file / or hacked?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I have a ubuntu box and found this "2" file in /var/run/systemd/sessions.  First thought was that I have been hacked because I don't recognize this IP address and have not explicitly configured this file as far as I know.

57.36.154.104.bc.googleusercontent.com

Note, my non-root user is rsmit.

Any idea what this "2" file is for?

```
root@willow1:/var/run/systemd/sessions# uname -a
Linux willow1 3.13.0-71-generic #114-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 1 02:34:22 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

root@willow1:/var/run/systemd/sessions# ls -altr
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 100 Feb 25 17:04 ..
prw------- 1 root root   0 Feb 27 19:42 2.ref
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 277 Feb 27 19:42 2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  80 Feb 27 19:42 .

root@willow1:/var/run/systemd/sessions# cat 2
# This is private data. Do not parse.
UID=1000
USER=rsmit
ACTIVE=1
STATE=active
REMOTE=1
KILL_PROCESSES=0
TYPE=tty
CLASS=user
CGROUP=/user/1000.user/2.session
FIFO=/run/systemd/sessions/2.ref
REMOTE_HOST=57.36.154.104.bc.googleusercontent.com
SERVICE=sshd
LEADER=2107
AUDIT=2
root@willow1:/var/run/systemd/sessions#
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also access this information via `loginctl show-session 2` and list all active sessions via `loginctl list-sessions`.

What the record means is that there's an active SSH connection coming from `57.36.154.104.bc.googleusercontent.com` to a user `rsmit`.

So unless you know someone from that domain should be logged in as `rsmit` I'd suggest seeking out *appropriate incident response immediately*.

(Disconnect the machine from network, check logs, check running processes etc.)

https://security.stackexchange.com/